# right syntax to use near 'update, stock_id) values (0, 0.0, 10018, 1, null, 0, null, 0)' at line 1

Tags: java, mysql, spring

Try to insert data into database. Everytime show this error

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'update, stock_id) values (0, 0.0, 10018, 1, null, 0, null, 0)' at line 1
```

**Database**

```
CREATE TABLE `stock_log` (   
   `stock_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,   
   `added_employee` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,  
   `added_item` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,  
   `added_quantity` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,   
   `added-price` double DEFAULT NULL,   
   `supplier` int(11) DEFAULT NULL NOT,
   `update` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,  
   `update_reason` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`stock_id`), 
   KEY `added_employee_idx` (`added_employee`),   
   KEY `added_item_idx` (`added_item`), 
   KEY `supplier_idx` (`employee`),
   CONSTRAINT `added_employee` FOREIGN KEY (`added_employee`) 
   REFERENCES `employee` (`employee_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
   CONSTRAINT `added_item` FOREIGN KEY (`added_item`) 
   REFERENCES `item_stock` (`item_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
   CONSTRAINT `supplier` FOREIGN KEY (`supplier`) 
   REFERENCES `supplier`(`supplier_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION )
   ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**Model**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="stock_log") 
public class Stock {

    @Id
    @Column(name="stock_id")    
    private int stockId;
    @Column(name="added_employee" )     
    private int employee;
    @Column(name="added_item")  
    private int item; 
    @Column(name="added_quantity")  
    private int addQty;
    @Column(name="added_price")     
    private double addedPrice;
    @Column(name="supplier")    
    private int supplier;
    @Column(name="update")  
    private String update;
    @Column(name="update_reason")   
    private String reason;      

    public Stock() {
        super();        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub     
    }

    public Stock(int stockId, int employee, int item, int addQty, 
               double addedPrice, int supplier, String update, String reason) {
        super();        
        this.stockId = stockId;
        this.employee = employee;
        this.item = item;
        this.addQty = addQty;
        this.addedPrice = addedPrice;
        this.supplier = supplier;
        this.update = update;
        this.reason = reason;   
    } 

    //getter setter

}
```

**Service**

```
public interface StockLogService {

  void saveAStock(Stock addedStock);

} 
@Service 
public class StockLogServiceImp implements StockLogService {

  @Resource     
  private StockLogRepository repository;

  @Override     
  public void saveAStock(Stock addedStock) {
    repository.saveAndFlush(addedStock);
  } 
}
```

**Repository**

```
public interface StockLogRepository extends JpaRepository<Stock, String> {   
}
```

**Controller**

```
@Controller 
public class CommonController {         
    @Autowired
    SupplierService supService;     
    @Autowired  
    StockLogService stockService;   
    Date todayDate = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();

    @RequestMapping(value="testing1")   
    public ModelAndView viewStock1() {      
        ModelAndView moView = new ModelAndView("testing1");             
        //Give empty stock object for ("/add")      
        moView.addObject("newStockCommand", new Stock());           
        return moView;  
    }   
    @RequestMapping(value="testing2")   
    public ModelAndView viewStock2(@ModelAttribute ("newStockCommand") Stock newStockCommand) {         
        ModelAndView moView = new ModelAndView("testing2");
        moView.addObject("addedStock", newStockCommand);
        stockService.saveAStock(newStockCommand);       
        return moView;  
     } 
}
```

**JSP**

[JSP screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9UeU.png)

Comment: I cleaned up the markup somewhat (using 4 spaces for code), but the code is still pretty unreadable. I'd recommend revisiting reformatting to make your question easier to read, which will encourage people to answer it! See [the editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for more information on formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`update` is a keyword. Try to rename the column in your table definition

```
update varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException - this exception shows that there is some issue with syntax. You can directly go to your syntax to know the problem. Column name "update" is a keyword and it is being used to write query to update any record in database. So, it is throwing exception. We can't use keywords as column name in any RDBMS.

Comment: It's a 'reserved word'